# How to access a list

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

So ive been working on reading from a list into an array and using the contents to make a calculations.

I have the array parts =

```
[Mildred, Bush, 45, 65, 45, 67, 65, Fred, Snooks, 23, 43, 54, 23, 76, Morvern, Callar, 65, 45, 34, 87, 76, Colin, Powell, 34, 54, 99, 67, 87, Tony, Blair, 67, 76, 54, 22, 12, Peter, Gregor, 99, 99, 99, 99, 99]
```

The assumption here is that every 7 values is one line of the text file. So what i want to do is take the name, change the numbers into integers, do calculations then output them.

The code i tried using is:

```
for(int i=0; i < 42;i=i+7) {
    float avg;
    float total;
    for (int x=2; x < 7;x++) {
        String number = parts[x];
        int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
        total = total + num;
    }
    avg = total/6;
    System.out.print(parts[i+1] + "," + parts[i+2] + + "Final Score is avg");
}
```

but i get hit with an error

```
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to List<String>
```

So i was wondering how I would go about solving this

Updated try:

String fileName = "Details.txt";

```
    String wfilename = "output.txt";

    // This will reference one line at a time
    String line = null;

    String temp;

    try {
        // FileReader reads text files in the default encoding.
        FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(fileName);

        FileWriter fileWriter = new FileWriter(wfilename);


        BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(fileWriter);

        // Always wrap FileReader in BufferedReader.
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);

        List<String> parts = new ArrayList<>();
        String [] temp2;

        while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            temp = line;
            temp2 = line.split(" ");

            for(int i=0; i<7; i++){
                parts.add(temp2[i]);
           }
            //System.out.println(line);
            bufferedWriter.write(line + "\n");
        }   
        System.out.print(parts);

        //conver to an array of strings
        String[] partsArray = parts.toArray();

        //code to do take values from array, do calculations and format to output
        for(int i=0; i < 42;i=i+7) {
            float avg;
            float total = 0;
            for (int x=2; x < 7;x++) {
                String number = partsArray[x];
                int num = Integer.parseInt(number);
                total = total + num;
            }
            avg = total/6;
            System.out.print(partsArray[i+1] + "," + partsArray[i+2] + "Final Score is" + avg);
        }

        // Always close files.
        bufferedReader.close();   
        bufferedWriter.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Unable to open file '" + fileName + "'");                
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Error reading file '" + fileName + "'");                  

    }
```

Comment: Your average calculation uses `total / 6` but there's only 5 values. Might want to fix that!

Comment: And `total` needs to be an `int` and initialized to `0`. The `avg` value should be `double`, not `float`, unless you specifically want limited precision, i.e. `double avg = total / 5d`. For the `print`, the names are at index `i` and `i+1`. Definitely not `i+2`, since you already know that's the first number.

Comment: Please show where you create your `parts` variable. And also show where you're filling it with data. Your edit shows that your filling it with `Object` instead of `String`. That is why it says *can't convert Object to String* when you try to access the data and store it inside a `String`.

Comment: @Zabuza updated the post. i used arraylist to initialise parts.

Answer (score 3):

You clearly have a list. You can either turn it into an array, like this

```
String[] partsArray = parts.toArray(new String[parts.size()]);
```

or begin accessing it like a list, like so

```
String number = parts.get(x);
```

Comment: Also, the index should be `i + x`, i.e. `parts.get(i + x)` or `partsArray[i + x]`

Comment: how would you go about implementing your first suggestion. I tried and i got hit by the error cant convert object to string. Il update my post to show my updated try

Comment: Oh, I see - `toArray()` returns `Object[]` - my mistake. You need `parts.toArray(new String[0])` which will return a `String[]`.

Answer (score -1):

The .toArray() should do the trick.

Ex: `String[] partsArr = parts.toArray();`

Some reading material: [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arraylist_toarray.htm)

Comment: Duplicate answer.

Comment: Saw that after reload.